# Is SSPR required for Password Writeback?

Tags: azure-active-directory

The docs seem to indicate that Self-Service Password Reset is required for password writeback, but do you need to enable SSPR for any users?
My goal is to allow logged in users to change their own passwords within AAD and then for the new password to be written back to ADDS via ADConnect.
But we don't want to enable SSPR and allow 'unauthenticated' users to change their passwords.
So I'm thinking I can just not add any users/groups to the SSPR-enabled setting but the password writeback should still work for all other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to what you said, Password writeback is the requirement to use SSPR. If you can provide the document you are referring, i can possibly have a look.

For the requirement that you have, you will have to enable password writeback in AD Connect and then configure SSPR. Under SSPR options, you can add a group and only members of that group would be able to reset the password.

As for the rest of the synced users in your AAD tenant, only the admin will be able to reset the password for them. The users will not be able to reset their password themselves.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much both. Just to be clear, if we enable Password Writeback in ADConnect, would a user be able to change their own password using myaccount.microsoft.com or similar? Would this work if their password is still active? Would it work if their password has expired but they still know it?

Comment: They will only be able to change it if they are enabled for SSPR explicitly. Enabling password writeback only allows admins to reset passwords for synced users.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks @abhijeetKohli

Comment: You can even block the admins from changing the permission by not allowing AD Connect service account apt permissions in onprem ad to reset/change the password of the user. Permissions are documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr-writeback#configure-account-permissions-for-azure-ad-connect

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, according to [Tutorial: Enable Microsoft Entra self-service password reset writeback to an on-premises environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr-writeback)
SSPR and Password Writeback are not prerequisies one of the other.
If you'll enable SSPR without Password Writeback, a user might change his AAD account password to be different from his OnPrem password (that is, until he'll change the OnPrem password and it will trigger a password sync towards AAD).
Enabling Password Writeback without enabling SSPR has no benefit, other then enabling the admin to reset OnPrem users passwords from the AzureAD interface.